# Enable Disk / Volume encryption without password prompt at boot

Tags: linux, security, encryption, disk-encryption, tpm

I need to encrypt Disk / volume / File system on Linux, but which will not require a password prompt at reboot.

While this will not prevent data theft if the entire system is snitched, it should at least ensure that data remains confidential if only the disk is attempted to be put on a different system.

The system has a `TPM` chip.

I looked at several solutions  -

- `LUKS-dmCrypt` : Whichever guide I have followed requires password upon boot. Further, encryption process requires a FS /volume format. Existing non-encrypted volume to encrypted seems like a complicated process which may be difficult to be carried out in an automated and unsupervised way. There are solutions such as [this](https://github.com/fox-it/linux-luks-tpm-boot), which bypass boot password prompt by storing it in `TPM` but I am not able to verify the validity and risks of using something like this, which hasn't many reviews or comments.
- `Veracrypt` : Veracrypt has `TPM` support, which I suppose does away for the need to provide a boot password, but [Veracrypt Release Notes](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Release%20Notes.html) only show `TPM` support for `Windows`, not `Linux`.
- Self Encrypting Disks : SED SSDs are a viable option, but even they require ATA password set in `BIOS` and would prompt for a password. I am not sure if it's possible to store the SED `AK` in `TPM` and whether it's likely to solve the problem. I haven't yet found any documentation from a manufacturer confirming this, searches on web have also proved futile.
- Storing the password / key in an unencrypted, removable disk like pen drive : Not an option
- Changing File system to another which allows something like this : Not an option. Only `ext4` or `xfs`...

I know `BitLocker` on `Windows` can enable drive level encryption and use `TPM` for a silent boot, but am not sure what works on `Linux`. Would like to use `SED` SSDs, but would a `TPM` solve the password at boot issue?

Is there any way I can use a SED or LUKS with / without `TPM` to forgo the need for a password during a reboot?

Comment: You can't do this without TPM. You need to store a secret that unlocks the encrypted disk somewhere and storing it in plain text would invalidate entire solution. Thus you need some kind of secure storage. This is what TPM does, it can store the secret providing it only for the trusted boot path. I haven't been able to do this on Linux yet. Veracrypt on Windows is far from perfect too, is works only with TPM 1.2 but not with 2.0.

Comment: @gronostaj  My system has a 'TPM` chip. I'd like to be able to use `TPM` but am not sure if it will solve the password at reboot issue. Especially for a SED and not sure how supported it is. I've not come across examples of SEDs with `TPM`. Even `LUKS` is just whispered...